# Two pivot tables on top of each other - VBA to aut. hide lines in between

Tags: excel, vba

In a worksheet I have two pivot tables on top of each other. I need a VBA macro that can hide the lines in between the two pivot tables. The challenge is the speed ... Using loops is extremely slow. Is there a way to solve this problem? So far I have created a macro that identifies the last row of the 1st pivot, table and the first row of the 2nd pivotable.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
    LastRow2 = .TableRange2.Row
    With .TableRange2
        LastRow2 = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1
    End With
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    TopRow1 = .TableRange1.Row
    With .TableRange1
        TopRow1 = .Row
    End With
End With

'Here I need some VBA to hide all rows in between LastRow2 and TopRow1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1 & ":A" & TopRow1 - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Thanks SJR - really simple and efficient ... It also works.

Answer (score 0):

Work out which Table is on top, then use `.TableRange2` to get the table range, and `Offset` to move up/down by a cell.  Then show/hide all of those rows in one action:

```
Dim ptTop As PivotTable, ptBottom As PivotTable

'Check which table is "Top" or "Bottom"
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Cells(1, 1).Row < ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2).TableRange2.Cells(1, 1).Row Then
    Set ptTop = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set ptBottom = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
Else
    Set ptTop = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
    Set ptBottom = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
End If

'Unhide from top of Top table to bottom of Bottom table
ActiveSheet.Range(ptBottom.TableRange2.Cells(ptBottom.TableRange2.Rows.Count, 1), _
    ptTop.TableRange2.Cells(1, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

'If there is at least 1 row between the tables
If ptTop.TableRange2.Cells(ptTop.TableRange2.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0) < ptBottom.TableRange2.Cells(1, 1).Row Then
    'Hide from below bottom of Top table to above top of Bottom Table
    ActiveSheet.Range(ptTop.TableRange2.Cells(ptTop.TableRange2.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0), _
        ptBottom.TableRange2.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

Set ptTop = Nothing
Set ptBottom = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks - This works perfect! Just one outstanding issue: If I was to add an additional row to the either top or bottom pivot table to make room for a non-pivot header, how's that done?

Comment: Adding a header to the top table, you want to have an `.Offset(-1,0)` after the `ptTop` cell in the `'Unhide` line.  Adding a header to the bottom table, you want to increase the `.Offset(-1,0)` on the `ptBottom` cell in the `'Hide'` block to `.Offset(-2,0)`, and the `.Offset(1,0)` on the `ptTop` in the `If` statement to `.Offset(2,0)`